# Toggle attribute(attr) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have called this function on `onchange` event on html checkbox.
When i click for first time all the controls in the table get disabled but when i reclick i want them to enable again.I want it javasrcipt not `$("#checkbox1").change`

```
function notewizardcheckbox() {
             $('#DispalyTable td').find('*').attr('disabled', "disabled");

    }
```

Plese help me
Thanks in Advance

Comment: *"I want it javasrcipt not `$("#checkbox1").change`"* That's JavaScript too! Why use jQuery but not for event handlers?

Comment: you can try is(:checked) property of jquery inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `prop()` and `is(":checked")` to check if it is checked or not..

```
function notewizardcheckbox(obj) {
    if($(obj).is(":checked")){
        $('#DispalyTable td').find('*').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
         $('#DispalyTable td').find('*').prop('disabled', false);
    }

}
```

and make sure you pass this in onchange event `onchange=notewizardcheckbox(this)`

OR

updated after all the comment i got.. :)

```
function notewizardcheckbox(obj) {

    $('#DispalyTable td').find('*').prop('disabled', obj.checked);


}
```

Comment: @Alnitak: [-1, not enough jQuery...](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: oh, and [don't repeat yourself!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).  It's inefficient coding, and introduces errors.  There is _no_ need for the `if` conditional when the very next thing you do is use the equivalent `true` / `false` value in the two opposing branches of the `if`.

Comment: ok guys!! sorry that i created this debate.. :) ....i simply thought i should get  it done with jquery... updated my answer..

Comment: @bipen suppose am using jquery version less than 1.6.1 say 1.4.1 how can i do this with attr

Comment: then `.attr('disabled', true);` to disable and `.attr('disabled', false);` to enable should work

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest:

```
function notewizardcheckbox(el) {
    // this does require you to pass in the element, though
    var el = el.nodeType && el.nodeType == 1 ? el : false;
    if (el === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $('#DisplayTable td').find('*').prop('disabled', !el.checked);

}
```

Personally, however, I can't see *any* valid reason not to use the `change()` method to handle the events, it is definitely valid JavaScript albeit it's a jQuery method, to emulate the `onchange`/`change` event.

So, unless you're looking for a plain JavaScript alternative there seems to good reason to avoid it, and even *with* that requirement, the native events can still be used.

References:

- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: i don't think this will work if the OP forgot to pass `this` in onchange event....

Comment: @David Thomas suppose am using jquery version less than 1.6.1 say 1.4.1 how can i do this with attr

Answer (score -1):

try

```
   $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
 if($(this).attr('checked',true))
  {
 $('#DispalyTable td').find('*').attr('disabled', false);
 }
else
{
  $('#DispalyTable td').find('*').attr('disabled', "disabled");
 }
});
```

Comment: your first call to `.attr()` is _setting_ the `checked` attribute, not  _testing_ it.